# Have sendmail authenticate users against dovecot (or passwd-style files)

Tags: debian, dovecot, sendmail, sasl

I have set up a Debian 10 mail server with sendmail and dovecot+virtual users in preparation of a migration (the old server is also running sendmail + dovecot, but older versions and with "real" users).

On the dovecot side, everything is peachy. I set up a passwd-file auth for testing, and I can log in, save drafts, and see locally delivered mail in my IMAP client.

However, when sending, sendmail is set up to require authentication, and I am looking for a way to let sendmail use the same auth database as dovecot, ideally even authenticate against dovecot (via SASL?).

Searching the web has not yielded any useful results, apparently the sendmail + dovecot combination is relatively rare. While I don't intend to stay on this forever, I am looking for a quick solution now to buy me time for migrating to a new stack.

Comment: I know it's more than 3 years you asked this but this is something I have been working on as well and finally figured it out.

Basically 2 ways, 1) dovecot-imap + dovecot-submission or 2) dovecot-imap + sendmail.  

I managed to get both working eventually but in the end, I opted to use sendmail for the msa because it's well known and time tested.  Solution posted below for the authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [dovecot-msa](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/submission_server/) on port msa(587) with "local sendmail like" relaying to `127.0.0.1:25`.
IMHO it is a simple way to use dovecot maintained passwords for IMAP, POP3 and SMTP.

Use `FEATURE(no_default_msa)` in sendmail.mc to disable sendmail listening on port 587.

**Warning:** making sendmail know list of valid virtual email addresses handled by dovecot is a separate issue [back-scatter prevention].

Comment: I’ll try this tomorrow!

Comment: So, after installing and configuring dovecot-submission, it accepts connections on :587 and authenticates correctly, but when passing them to the local sendmail, that says it does not know any users. I have configured sendmail with a mailertable but it does not seem to apply it. Down the rabbit hole…

Comment: Have you made any changes in sendmail config to integrate it with dovecot? [mailers, relays, local_mailer, …]. There are two obvious ways: a) periodically export list of valid email addresses from dovecot to format sendmail likes b) for SMALL installations make sendmail read TEXT files in dovecot config.  Accepting every email in domains handled by dovecot is not a good choice in "spam era".

Comment: Yes, I had set up dovecot-lmtp and local delivery works, I have tried both `mailertable` and `virtusertable` to have sendmail pass mail to dovecot-lmtp, but failed. I was close to giving up and just reproducing the old setup with system users, but then decided to just go with postfix, see if I can make that work, first.

Comment: I’m going to accept the answer as it’s absolutely right but sendmail is annoying. Another option would be to have sendmail authenticate against dovecot-sasl, but I couldn’t figure that out either.

Comment: @moeffju In sendmail config try `FEATURE(local_lmtp)` or `FEATURE(local_procmail)` [Both require additional parameters].  `local_procmail` will allow you to execute dovecot-lda program as local mailer substitute.

Comment: @moeffju Sorry, both above methods without extra tricks will deal with "domain less" email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure cyrus-sasl to auth against dovecot using remote imap capability.

For example in CentOS (auth against local IMAP/Dovecot):

```
/etc/sysconfig/saslauthd
```

```
MECH=rimap
FLAGS=" -O 127.0.0.1"
```

However, this might be problematic, because you are going to do much more connections to IMAP server and in logs, you will see login attempts from localhost so bear that in mind.

Comment: Debian doesn't have `/etc/sysconfig/saslauthd`.  How would one do this on debian?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian you would edit `/etc/default/saslauthd` and change these lines:

```
# Example: MECHANISMS="pam"
MECHANISMS="rimap"

# Additional options for this mechanism. (default: none)
# See the saslauthd man page for information about mech-specific options.
MECH_OPTIONS="-O 127.0.0.1"
```

and, optionally (in same file), if you are using dovecot's userdb with %u (user@domain usernames), you need to add the -r option to the options so that saslauthd passes the @domain to rimap:

```
OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
```

If you don't add the -r to the options, then, on the dovecot side, you will need to use %l instead of %u, and your dovecot users file will contain 'username' lines instead of 'username@domain' lines.

For example:

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%l /etc/dovecot/users
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%l /etc/dovecot/users

  # Default fields that can be overridden by passwd-file
  default_fields = uid=dovecot-virtual gid=dovecot-virtual home=/home/dovecot-virtual/%l
}
```

Personally I opted to add -r to saslauthd because then I can authenticate users with the same username in different domain names in both sendmail and dovecot.